# C++ Interfaces Exchanging

Tags: c++, abstract-class, pure-virtual

I'm trying to work with C++ java/C# like interfaces by creating classes that have only pure virtual methods, like the following: (this is just an example)

```
class IMyInterface
{
public:
    virtual int someFunc() = 0;
    virtual ~IMyInterface() {}
};
```

Everything is fine until I was stuck implementing a method that exchanges two elements in an array of `IMyInterface`, since it's not allowed in C++ to instantiate an interface as the compiler will complain about `temp` not implementing `someFunc()`.

```
void Exchange(IMyInterface* array, int i, int j)
{
    IMyInterface temp = array[i]; // not allowed
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}
```

so I had to change the interface class definition and get rid of pure virtual function and supply a "default" implementation of the method like so:

```
class IMyInterface
{
public:
    virtual int someFunc()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    virtual ~IMyInterface() {}
};
```

The problem is that `IMyInterface` is not an interface anymore, it doesn't force whatever class that will inherit from it to implement `someFunc()`.

Anyway around this?

Comment: `since it's not allowed in C++ to instantiate an interface` I'm not aware of _any_ language in which that makes sense. **What really is your problem?** You are not supposed to instantiate interfaces, but _inherit_ from them.

Comment: If you need to create instances of `IMyInterface` it is not a interface(*aka* Abstract class) anyways. You can either have a interface or not have one. You cannot expect it to be a interface and then want to create instances of it . You cannot get best of both worlds.

Comment: Interfaces should almost always be used as pointers.

Comment: @Justin: No, nonsense. Sorry.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can you give me an example of how an interface would be useful by value?

Comment: @JustinMeiners: I reject the premise of your question. Interfaces should be used as base classes to a complete type, _and in no other way_. Classes are not pointers, and they are not values.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That almost defeats the purpose - Code can refer to interface without knowing the implementation. This his how almost all Java code is designed. List = new ArrayList()  MyFunc(List) - List is an interface. Array List is the concrete type but we can write code that does not care about implementation.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: So? If your interface is not a base class of any other type, then it is impossible to use it, and you might as well not bother at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So almost every single thing that will use an interface will use it to represent some object without worry about the complete implementation. and in that context the only way to use it is by pointer. Only one thing will ever use it for anything else - Subclasses.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit point is - the way he is trying to use an interface class will not work. He is trying to use a value which is not defined, by using a pointer to an interface he can accomplish what he needs to do.

Comment: Okay, a pointer to an object, that is of type pointer-to-interface, yes. You said earlier that interfaces should be "used as pointers" which is quite different, and quite impossible. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Haha you fully understood what I meant

Comment: @AlokSave You and LightnessRacesInOrbit are both trying to trip him on on semantics - you both fully understand what his problem is and what he needs

Comment: @JustinMeiners: And now he'll learn the _proper_ terminology with which to explain his problem to others. Don't underestimate the value of precision.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Stackoverflow is not place to show how smart you are - its to help other people get smarter. Not everyone is a genius like you and knows the exact terminology to ask their question in - that is why they ask. What would be helpful would be to actually answer his question, and in your answer correct his terminally for further clarification. It's not like his question was not clear on what he was asking - thats why he had code. Responding "not possible" to a deliberately misinterpreted question helps nobody unless you also guide them in the right direction.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: `Stackoverflow is not place to show how smart you are` Yes it is. `Not everyone is a genius like you and knows the exact terminology to ask their question in - that is why they ask.` And that's why I have provided it. `What would be helpful would be to actually answer his question` I'm not obliged to, and I also don't need to since you already did. Thanks for playing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit your great attitude and kindness is sure to make you a success! (BTW nobody had answered the question when you made that comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces are not fully defined objects so you cannot create instances of them. They are of an undefined size and structure so they obviously cannot be created or used in the value context.  You can however **create pointers to interfaces** (Happy Guys?) because a pointer to an object is very well defined. The sample code could become:

```
void Exchange(IMyInterface** array, int i, int j)
{
    IMyInterface* temp = array[i]; // allowed :)
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}
```

If the operation is something that should be done by value perhaps a template function would be more appropriate.

Comment: @AhmedFakhry Perhaps you misunderstand the IMyInterface** array syntax. It is a pointer to a pointer - in this case a pointer to an array of pointers :P. Simply adding a &array will give you an array of pointer objects. Perhaps it could be better understood by reading this typedef IMyInterface* ptr; ptr* array or  IMyInterface* array[20]

Comment: I don't see using array is a good c++ practice, why not vector with smart  pointers?

Comment: @billz I agree which would be defined as std::vector<IMyInterface*> array; but maybe he has a reason - or maybe it is an exercise. Also there is no assumable reason why smart pointers should be used in this code.

Comment: Oh yes I understand what you mean, sorry.